# count messages last 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get get the count of how many messages a user sent in the last 24 hours.  My code is only returning the integer 1 when this is simply not true.  What am I doing wrong? 
My dates are in this format: 2012-03-01 10:57:32

Thanks!

```
    function get_quota($data)
    {   
        $sql = "select * FROM messages WHERE user_id = {$data['id']} 
                    AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        $count=$this->db->count_all_results();  
        return $count;     
    }
```

Comment: what datatype is your `time` column?

Comment: why you dont use "select count(*) FROM..."? I think is less load for server.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you are returning a lot of data (with a select *) just to count the messages!This is a terrible waste of bandwith and processing power. Do

```
function get_quota($data)
    {   
        $sql = "select count(*) as howmany FROM messages WHERE user_id = {".$data['id']."} AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
        $myResults = $this->db->query($sql);
        retrn $myResults->row()->howmany;
    }
```

and return the result

EDIT - Your error was that `$data['id']` is not evaluated inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem (and of the wrong result) is that you are mixing two ways of accessing the database:

- with the query() function you effectively execute the SQL which is passed as its argument.  This function returns a Result object which would need to be exploited.
- with the count_all_results() function you are running a "SELECT COUNT(*)"  (or something equivalent) on the current state of a query/selection criteria [which you must previously build by chaining operators such as ***like***, ***not_like***, ***from***, ***where*** etc.].  The function returns an integer that is the number of rows.
  In the case of the snippet of the question, the Active Record context is completely reset [right after the query() call], and since you don't even pass it a table name or other criteria, the function returns the value 1 (maybe because the result is one error or some' like that).

**You should therefore pick *one* or the other approach**, ie. specifically, either:

```
// Note how we use COUNT(*) as suggested in other comments and answers, since
// we do not need the actual data, just the count
// If you are intent on the original, very inefficient approach, use the 
// select * ... query and then get the number of rows with something like
// $count = $myResults->num_rows();
// Also, unrelated, note how the $data['id'] expression was removed from the
// string literal since it needs to be evaluated by PHP not by SQL (thanks
// to Nichola Peluchetti for pointing that out).
$sql = "select COUNT(*) AS NbOfRows FROM messages WHERE user_id = {".$data['id']."} 
        AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$myResults = $this->db->query($sql);
$count = $myResults->row()->NbOfRows
```

or

```
   // build your search criteria
   $this->db->from('messages');
   $this->db->where('user_id', $data['id']);
   $this->db->where('time >',  'DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
   // $this->db->where("'time >' DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)")
   $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

For the 2nd approach, I'm not 100% of how/if the literal 'DATE_SUB()...' effectively gets passed and executed by SQL (which it must since it is a SQL function) but that's another issue; to be safe, use the commented out syntax which uses a single *where* expression passed as a single string instead.

The point of this answer is that you need to use either ***query()*** method or ***count*_all_*results()*** but not both.  And, regardless of the approach, you need to exploit the underlying results as prescribed in the [**documentation**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: In any case he was using `$data['id']` inside double quotes hoping that it was evaluated :)

Comment: Good catch, Nichola, I was so focused on the other mistakes that I didn't notice this. Indeed, as written in the question's snippet, the query is not relevant at all to the value eventually assigned to $count.   I'll edit my answer to weed out this secondary bug.